# Drupal 8.2.1 Logout Post Request

Tags: angular, drupal, rpc, logout, drupal-8

I've been using the new RPC endpoints that were added in Drupal 8.2.1 to create an Angular 2 application that uses Drupal as the backend. I can succesfully log the user in and a cookie is set. However, using the logout end point as explained in the following post [Additional RPC Endpoints](https://www.drupal.org/node/2720655#comment-11761718) does not seem to work for me.

```
curl --header "Content-type: application/json" --request POST \
http://drupal.d8/user/logout?_format=json
```

This request returns a 403 forbidden error. I have looked around and found very little about this topic.

Here is the HTTP request that is made:

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

this.userLogoutUrl = 'http://localhost:8888/user/logout?_format=json';
return this._http.post(this.userLogoutUrl, {headers: headers, withCredentials: true})
  .map(res => res.json());
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray added

Comment: I have the same issues, everything works (register user, login user, create nodes) but the logout functionality also gives me a 403 forbidden. I've tried about everything.